# ECSlidingViewController with Push and Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I am using `ECSlidingViewController` with storyboards. `ECSlidingVC` is my root (starting) controller. My left menu is a `TableView` with static cells, and my `TopViewController` is a navigation controller. I want to have a single `NavigationController` for all my app.

From my left menu i cant use push or unwind segues, i understand that part though. i can only use `ECSlidingSegue` which changes `topviewController` of `ECSlidingVC` and which destroys my navigation controller and it's stack.

i want to be able to go back from a menu item VC to previous VC in my main nav controller. lets say basically i want `ECSlidingVC` to not change `topViewController` but push destination `viewController` to my source.`topViewController`.`navigationController`.

Also i need to use unwind segues with my menu items. i need to go back to a VC in my main nav controller.

i inspected `ECSlidingSegue` source code and all it does is to replace `topViewController`.

is there a built in method (or segue) in `ECSlidingViewController` for pushing (or unwinding) VC into source.`topViewController`.`navController` or do i need to implement a custom segue myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to go is for you to implement a custom segue yourself. Something like `ECSlidingNavigationSegue`, which would look for your `topViewController`, then check whether it's a `UINavigationController` and then push the `destinationController` to it.

It's basically the same `perform` method as the `ECSlidingSegue`, but with this feature of pushing a controller to the `topViewController` instead of replacing it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone haven't found answer, I did it in this way.

1- `#import "UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController.h"` to your menuViewController
2- Set stroboardID of your destinationViewController to "someID"
3- When triggering some action, in backend, use this code:

```
    if(self.slidingViewController.currentTopViewPosition == ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionCentered){
        [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];
    }
    else{
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someID"];
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
    }
```